# Django - Change timeuntil language without changing application language

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using the `timeuntil` tag of Django templates. I'd like to obtain the output in a language different from English, but without changing the `LANGUAGE_CODE` in `settings.py` (which would change the language of the entire application).
I'm not doing localization, and I don't want to do it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) which will call django's `timeuntil` with different locale.  For example italian version will look like this:

```
# app/templatetags/timeuntil_it.py
from django.template.base import Library
from django.template.defaultfilters import timeuntil_filter
from django.utils import translation

register = Library()

@register.filter
def timeuntil_it(value, arg=None):
    with translation.override('it'):
        time_until = timeuntil_filter(value, arg)
    return time_until
```

And in the template you should load this template library:

```
{% load timeuntil_it %}
{{ future_time|timeuntil_it }}
```